# Multidimensional array in Jenkinsfile (Groovy)

Tags: arrays, jenkins, multidimensional-array, groovy

I would like to declare a multidimensional array in my Jenkinsfile which holds deploy data for different environments. In PHP I would declare it like so:

```
$deployData = [];

$deployData['test']['user'] = 'testuser';
$deployData['test']['host'] = 'testhost';
$deployData['test']['path'] = 'testpath';

$deployData['acceptance']['user'] = 'accuser';
$deployData['acceptance']['host'] = 'acchost';
$deployData['acceptance']['path'] = 'accpath';

$deployData['production']['user'] = 'produser';
$deployData['production']['host'] = 'prodhost';
$deployData['production']['path'] = 'prodpath';
```

How would one achieve the same results in a Jenkinsfile (Groovy)? I tried creating a new String array:

```
def deployData = new String[3][3][1]

deployData['test']['user'] = 'testuser'
deployData['test']['host'] = 'testhost'
deployData['test']['path'] = 'testpath'

deployData['acceptance']['user'] = 'accuser'
deployData['acceptance']['host'] = 'acchost'
deployData['acceptance']['path'] = 'accpath'

deployData['production']['user'] = 'produser'
deployData['production']['host'] = 'prodhost'
deployData['production']['path'] = 'prodpath'
```

When running the above code in Jenkins I got the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

Full trace: https://pastebin.com/ZEBRFuAW

Does anyone know how to create multidimensional arrays like the first PHP example (including the same value assignment for readability)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not an array, thats a map of maps.  You can make one in a single line like so:

```
def deployData = [test:       [user: 'testuser',
                               host: 'testhost',
                               path: 'testpath'],
                  acceptance: [user: 'accuser',
                               host: 'acchost',
                               path: 'accpath'],
                  production: [user: 'produser',
                               host: 'prodhost',
                               path: 'prodpath']]
```

Or:

```
def deployData = [:]

deployData.test       = [user: 'testuser', host: 'testhost', path: 'testpath']
deployData.acceptance = [user: 'accuser',  host: 'acchost',  path: 'accpath']
deployData.production = [user: 'produser', host: 'prodhost', path: 'prodpath']
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Any idea how I can use the PHP like assigning syntax in my example? I would like to implement it like so for readability.

Comment: @Gun5m0k3 added a different way of putting it... I see it as more readable than in the question, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder I guess ;-)